# CakePHP ClassRegistry best practice

Tags: php, cakephp

I have some Models that are not associated each other, when I need to fetch some info among them, should I use `ClassRegistry::init('ModelName')`? Is it a good practice?

The controller should pass information between "not-interconnected" models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good practice?

CR is fine if there is no other way to get it. In a controller and shell you can use the `$uses` property to load additional models as well. Note that the first item in the list is going to be the primary `$modelClass` property of your controller.

> The controller should pass information between "not-interconnected" models?

No, technically it can but all data manipulation should happen in the models. So pass whatever data you have to deal with from your controller to a model method and process it there and return it in the case your controller needs it again for something.